# Reactor Webflux runs throws OutOfMemoryError while reading from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm writing a reactor script to read <22GB of 1457 json files (~14.2MB each) from S3, convert each line (single json item) into POJO `MagicObject`, and then log it (for testing purposes). Script is being executed on m5.xlarge   instance (4 vCPU, 16GB memory).

This is the code that I'm using:

```
private static final S3AsyncClient S3_CLIENT = S3AsyncClient.create();
private static final String PREFIX = "some/prefix"; // not actual one
private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

public void readAndLog() {

    Flux.from(S3_CLIENT.listObjectsV2Paginator(ListObjectsV2Request
                .builder()
                .bucket(EVENT_STORE_BUCKET)
                .prefix(PREFIX)
                .maxKeys(1) // to reduce memory pressure, downloading one object at the time
                .build())
            )
            .flatMap(list -> Flux.fromIterable(list.contents()))
            .flatMap(s3Object -> Mono.fromFuture(() -> S3_CLIENT.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(EVENT_STORE_BUCKET)
                    .key(s3Object.key())
                    .build(), AsyncResponseTransformer.toBytes()))
                    .onTerminateDetach(),
                    4 // Limiting concurrency to 4 threads
            )
            .flatMap(bytesWrapper -> Flux.using(
                    () -> getAllLines(bytesWrapper),
                    Flux::fromStream,
                    Stream::close
            ))
            .flatMap(this::getObjectFromJson)
            .doOnNext(log::info)
            .blockLast();
}

@SneakyThrows
private Stream<String> getAllLines(BytesWrapper bytesWrapper) {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesWrapper.asByteArray());
    Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(decoder);
    return buffered.lines();
}

@SneakyThrows
private Mono<MagicObject> getToBeDeletedEventStore(String item) {
    return Mono.just(MAPPER.readValue(item, MagicObject.class));
}
```

The script starts fetching and logging items correctly, however I can see that memory slowly decrease, until it inevitably the OOM happens.

Things I tried:

1. Change the concurrency to 1 (i.e., making this sequential).
2. Adding parallel after `listObjectsV2Paginator`:

   ```
    Flux.from(...)
            .parallel(4)
            .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            // ...
            .sequential()
            .doOnNext(log::info)
            .blockLast();
   ```

What can I do to deal with this?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have multiple flatmaps but you only limit concurrency for one of them. You should either limit all of them or merge them into a single flatmap

Comment: But why in the first place am I running oom? As you can see, information is not saved anywhere. Seems like some of the objects become permanent and eat up the memory, or they're not cleaned up.